# How to disable TRACE in niginx conf file

Tags: security, nginx, trace, nginx-location

Assume my web app is hosted on https://example.com, I am testing my HTTP verbs on my server, I have nginx there,

curl -v -X TRACE https://example.com

For above I am getting a response. Instead, I should get 404 or other.

I had tried the below conf in Nginx server location block.

```
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ){
    return 444;
 }
```

This works for me but TRACE is still allowed. How should I stop it?

Comment: I had tried adding below in my location block too,                                
  if ( $request_method = TRACE ) {
        return 404;
    }

Comment: What response are you getting instead? By default nginx returns a 405 response to a TRACE request.

Comment: @palako It returns me HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `limit_except` instead, like this:

```
location / {
    limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }
}
```